# problems generating table with ngFor?

Tags: html, json, angular, ngfor

I need to create a table with information from an array of Json objects.
Suppose that the data arrives in the following format.

```
profiles = [{
        id: 1,
        userId:1000,
        profile: "Cars 2018",
        parentId: 0,
        created: "00.00.0000 00:00:00",
        fields: [
                    {id:1, type:"text", name: "Brand"},
                    {id:2, type:"decimal", name: "velocity"},
                    {id:3, type:"int", name: "leather"}
        ],
        data: [
            { id:1, value:'BMW 2018', profileId:1, fieldId:1  },
            { id:2, value:'130 Km/h', profileId:1, fieldId:2 },
            { id:3, value:'Yes', profileId:1, fieldId:3 },
            { id:4, value:'Mercedez Benz 2018', profileId:1, fieldId:1  }, 
            { id:5, value:'180 Km/h', profileId:1, fieldId:2 },
            { id:6, value:'No', profileId:1, fieldId:3 }
        ]
    }];
```

So far all simple, I could just do this and go ...

```
<div *ngFor="let field of profiles">
   <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let link of field.fields">
              {{ link.name }}
          </th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td *ngFor="let dt of field.data">
            {{ dt.value }}
         </td>
       </tr> 
     </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

But the result will be:

```
Brand     |  Velocity   | Leather |
BMW 2018  |   130 Km/h  |  Yes    | Mercedez Benz 2018  | 130 Km/h | No
```

How to make the data adapt to the number of columns?

UPDATE--------
I added 'fieldId' to data, so the data should display in their correspondent field...

Comment: What is the corelation between the header and the data? I dont see any match. Is it by id?

Comment: You only have 3 headers, but you are rendering 6 columns. How else should the information be displayed if you dont handle that?

Comment: @ZivWeissman with 'fieldId'...

Comment: @Jota.Toledo that's the point of my question, how to handle the info depending how many fields...

Comment: try something?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just manipulate the data from you component class.

Try this

```
let profiles = [{
        id: 1,
        userId:1000,
        profile: "Cars 2018",
        parentId: 0,
        created: "00.00.0000 00:00:00",
        fields: [
                    {id:1, type:"text", name: "Brand"},
                    {id:2, type:"decimal", name: "velocity"},
                    {id:3, type:"int", name: "leather"}
        ],
        data: [
            { id:1, value:'BMW 2018', profileId:1  },
            { id:2, value:'130 Km/h', profileId:1 },
            { id:3, value:'Yes', profileId:1 },
            { id:4, value:'Mercedez Benz 2018', profileId:1  },
            { id:5, value:'180 Km/h', profileId:1 },
            { id:6, value:'No', profileId:1 }
        ]
    }]; 
//Create a buffer for current data
let dataTable = profiles;
let index = 0;
for(let x of profiles){
//Create a data container
  let data = [];
//Number of iterations base on the header
  let iterations = x.data.length / x.fields.length;

  for(let r = 0; r < iterations; r++){
      data.push(dataTable[index].data.splice(0, x.fields.length));
  }

//Equate it since array are mutable
  x.data = data;
  index++;
}
```

Then in your html file do it like this

```
<div *ngFor="let field of profiles">
   <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let link of field.fields">
              {{ link.name }}
          </th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let dt of field.data">
         <td *ngFor="let y of dt">
            {{ y.value }}
         </td>
       </tr> 
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: `data.splice(0, x.fields.length)` will always return the same [0..x.fields.length], independent of the iteration. So you will end up with N rows that display the same info. What if OP doesn't want to mutate the original object?

Comment: My bad, forgot that splice mutates the original array

Comment: @AmayaSan Yeahhh that works!!! One million of thank you!!! wow I was three days trying to find a solution.

Comment: nice to hear, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

you should modify your data in code so that it's what you actually want to display.  You could use the array map operator for this pretty easily:

```
profiles = profiles.map(profile => {
    profile.data = profile.data.filter(d => !!profile.fields.find(f => f.id === d.id));
    return profile;
});
```

You wouldn't want to attempt this logic in template as template logic should be as clean and simple as you can make it.  Your tools / capabilities are far greater in code.

if this is coming through an observable you could use the array map operator within the rx map operator

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still the same result as I put in my question...

Comment: then you didn't set it correctly, update your question with how you tried to do this and I can tell you where you went wrong.  Or just add more code about how / when profiles gets set in your controller.